# Vuejs : Filtering data using input and checkbox

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to filter my data using input and checkbox. Below is the code script that works as you can see but does not work as I want it to. According to the script; When no text is entered in the input field, the checkboxes do not work even if they are checked. Where could I be doing wrong?

```
<input v-model="search_all_task">

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" true-value="title1" false-value="" v-model="dashSelect3" @id="dashSelect1 = $event.target.value" id="checkbox1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">Title 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" true-value="title2" false-value="" v-model="dashSelect3" @id="dashSelect2 = $event.target.value" id="checkbox2">
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox2">Title 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" true-value="title3" false-value="" v-model="dashSelect3" @id="dashSelect3 = $event.target.value" id="checkbox1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">Title 3</label>
```

```
data() {
   return {
     allTaskDashboard : [
           { id: 1, title: "title1", content: "content1" },
{ id: 2, title: "title2", content: "content2" },
{ id: 3, title: "title3", content: "content3" }
       
       ]
 }
},
computed:{
   filterDashboardTask(){

      return this.allTaskDashboard.filter(item =>{
         return(
            this.search_all_task.length === 0 || item.content.toLowerCase().includes(this.search_all_task.toLowerCase())
            || this.dashSelect2.includes(item.title) 
            || this.dashSelect1.includes(item.title)
            || this.dashSelect3.includes(item.title)
            ) 
      });
   },
}
```

```
<div v-for="item in filterDashboardTask">
// This another parametres
</div>
```

Comment: I did not see `filterDashboardTask` in your template code. From where you are computing this ?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ? You want to filter your array based on search value and title at the same time ? For example I selected title1 and after I see only title1 and content1 but I can use search input to filter filteredArray again ? For example I searched for content2 and I see nothing ?